# How to strip a number in the output of an executable?

Tags: bash

I run an executable which outputs a lot of lines to stdout. The last line is

```
Run in 100 seconds
```

The code in the C program of the executable to write the last line is

```
printf("Ran in %g seconds\n", time);
```

So there is a newline character at the end.

I want to strip the last number, e.g. 100, from the stdout, so in bash

```
./myexecutable > output
```

Then I wonder how to further parse `output` to get the time number in bash? Do I need some applications to do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'Ran in \K\d+' output
```

or

```
grep -oP '(?<=Ran in )\d+(?= seconds)'  output
```

Comment: Actually the number may be decimal. so shall we change `\d` to something else?

Comment: @Tim Since we are using lookarounds in the second form, you might as well replace `\d+` with `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

```
s='Run in 100 seconds'
```

Using `tr`:

```
tr -cd '[[:digit:]]' <<< "$s"
100
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< "$s"
100
```

**However if you want to grab last number in a line** then use this **lookahead regex**:

```
s='Run 10 in 100 seconds'
grep -oP '\d+(?!\D*\d)' <<< "$s"
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, use `tail` to grab the last line (`tail -n 1 <file>`) and extract the number by either -

Using `sed` with three pattern groups and printing the second group match:

`tail -n 1 output | sed 's/\(^Run in \)\([0-9]\+\)\( seconds$\)/\2/g'`

Using `awk` to print the third (`$3`) token:

`tail -n 1 output | awk '{print $3}'`